# Format and sort text-based log file by hour and number of events matching search criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code snippet that will take a Cisco ASA log file and parse output of a specific search criteria to a separate text file. Each line of the text file looks like this:

```
2011-04-13 08:53:25 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 08:53:25 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302016: Teardown UDP connection 41996837 for Workstations:192.168.2.92/1885 to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 duration 0:02:01 bytes 2638
2011-04-13 08:54:28 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 08:54:28 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302015: Built inbound UDP connection 41998715 for Workstations:192.168.2.60/4377 (192.168.2.60/4377) to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 (192.168.1.14/88)
2011-04-13 08:54:45 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 08:54:45 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302015: Built inbound UDP connection 41998861 for Workstations:192.168.2.145/4939 (192.168.2.145/4939) to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 (192.168.1.14/88)
2011-04-13 08:54:45 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 08:54:45 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302015: Built inbound UDP connection 41998869 for Workstations:192.168.2.145/4941 (192.168.2.145/4941) to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 (192.168.1.14/88)
2011-04-13 08:54:45 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 08:54:45 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302015: Built inbound UDP connection 41998873 for Workstations:192.168.2.145/4945 (192.168.2.145/4945) to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 (192.168.1.14/88)
2011-04-13 08:54:46 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 08:54:46 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302015: Built inbound UDP connection 41998884 for Workstations:192.168.2.57/4868 (192.168.2.57/4868) to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 (192.168.1.14/88)
2011-04-13 08:54:46 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 08:54:46 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302015: Built inbound UDP connection 41998888 for Workstations:192.168.2.57/4872 (192.168.2.57/4872) to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 (192.168.1.14/88)
2011-04-13 08:55:21 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 08:55:21 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302015: Built inbound UDP connection 41999271 for Workstations:192.168.2.140/4460 (192.168.2.140/4460) to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 (192.168.1.14/88)
2011-04-13 09:03:04 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 09:03:04 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302015: Built inbound UDP connection 42003790 for Workstations:192.168.2.127/1859 (192.168.2.127/1859) to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 (192.168.1.14/88)
2011-04-13 09:03:04 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 09:03:04 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302014: Teardown TCP connection 42003789 for Workstations:192.168.2.127/1858 to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 duration 0:00:00 bytes 1726 TCP FINs
2011-04-13 09:03:05 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 09:03:05 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302016: Teardown UDP connection 42002706 for Workstations:192.168.2.127/1824 to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 duration 0:02:01 bytes 2722
2011-04-13 10:09:48 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 10:09:48 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302015: Built inbound UDP connection 42064964 for Workstations:192.168.2.73/1214 (192.168.2.73/1214) to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 (192.168.1.14/88)
2011-04-13 10:10:26 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 10:10:26 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302016: Teardown UDP connection 42061792 for Workstations:192.168.2.91/4189 to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 duration 0:02:01 bytes 2716
2011-04-13 10:10:26 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 10:10:26 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302016: Teardown UDP connection 42061793 for Workstations:192.168.2.91/4190 to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 duration 0:02:01 bytes 2719
2011-04-13 10:10:27 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 10:10:27 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302016: Teardown UDP connection 42061798 for Workstations:192.168.2.91/4194 to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 duration 0:02:02 bytes 2722
2011-04-13 11:26:02 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 11:26:02 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302015: Built inbound UDP connection 42072419 for Workstations:192.168.2.81/1205 (192.168.2.81/1205) to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 (192.168.1.14/88)
2011-04-13 11:26:27 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 11:26:27 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302015: Built inbound UDP connection 42072489 for Workstations:192.168.2.98/2209 (192.168.2.98/2209) to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 (192.168.1.14/88)
2011-04-13 11:26:28 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 11:26:28 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302016: Teardown UDP connection 42072239 for Workstations:192.168.2.127/2162 to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 duration 0:02:01 bytes 2537
2011-04-13 11:26:28 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 11:26:28 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302016: Teardown UDP connection 42072240 for Workstations:192.168.2.127/2163 to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 duration 0:02:01 bytes 2552
2011-04-13 11:26:57 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 11:26:57 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302015: Built inbound UDP connection 42072538 for Workstations:192.168.2.23/3146 (192.168.2.23/3146) to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 (192.168.1.14/88)
2011-04-13 11:27:31 Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 :Apr 13 11:27:31 PDT: %ASA-session-6-302016: Teardown UDP connection 42072362 for Workstations:192.168.2.137/4748 to Servers:192.168.1.14/88 duration 0:02:01 bytes 2618
```

The program, right now, copies over all matching log entries that match a given search criteria (in my case, 192.168.1.14/88), and writes them to a new text file. However, now I want to format the output of this file so it's in an easily-interpreted manner. So now, I want the program to output the search criteria like this:

```
(first column date/time with hour only, second IP address, third port number, fourth # of events)
2011-04-13T08 192.168.1.14  88  8
2011-04-13T09 192.168.1.14      88      3
2011-04-13T10 192.168.1.14      88      4
2011-04-13T11 192.168.1.14      88      6
```

I'm struggling with figuring out how to do this. Any suggestions?

```py
import os

# Ask user for file input
fileName = input("File Name to Read: ")
writeFile = input("File Name to Write to: ")

print("Reading data from file: " + fileName)
print("All matching lines of input file will be output to " + writeFile)
print("")
print("Use this format for IP/Port Searching: X.X.X.X:Port")
search = input("Enter the IP address and port to find data from: ")
print("")
print("Now searching " + fileName + " for data matching IP/Port " + search)
print("Analyzing data from file: " +fileName)
print("This may take a while, depending on the size of the data.")

f = open(fileName, 'r')
writeFile = open(writeFile, 'w')

num_lines = 0
num_events = 0

with open(fileName) as f:
    for i, l in enumerate(f):
        if search in l:
            num_events += 1
            writeFile.write(l)
writeFile.close()
f.close()

# Print number of matching events
print("Search complete! I found ",num_events," events matching your search criteria " + search)
```

EDIT: I can do it from memory as well by declaring an empty list and writing each line to a list, I just chose to do it to a text file. If it's easier to do it by parsing through a list from memory, I'm open to that.

Comment: Most solutions will be easier to do in memory.  What you may want to do if put your data in a `pandas dataframe`  then when the formatting is done send that dataframe to a txt file. If the data you are handling isn't to big for memory. Or a list of `namedtuples` would consume less memory and not require another pip install.

Comment: Actually if I am reading your question right you can just format each line before you do `writeFile.write(l)`.  Just parse through the string to find the stuff you want. I can give you a coded example if you provided a few more inputs and the expected output for those inputs.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse See recent edits, I updated it with sample inputs/expected output.

Comment: Can you add the a few expected outputs for those inputs? Not just a generalization but what you would actually want for those inputs.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Updated with requested information. Program should read IP address immediately following "Servers:" and report the number of instances, per hour, events matching that input occur. So for example, for Server IP Address 192.168.1.14 port 88, there are 3 events from the input file I've included that occur during the 0900-1000 hour.

Comment: Can you get some kind of delimiter to be inserted when you pull this. Your question would be easy to handle in pandas as `Error - Syntactical Remorse` mentioned, but it will be much easier with delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

I used regex to find the important parts in each line of the log file.  This answer could be much shorter, cleaner, and understandable if we could do all this in memory using a `DataFrame` but this solution reads only an hours worth of lines at a time before writing a new line to the new log file (thus less memory intensive).

I tried to comment everything and left a couple `print`s in the code to help you see how it works.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

input_file = 'test.txt'
output_file = 'logsoutput.txt'
print("Started")
# This is how I am keeping track of unique ip/port pairs we see every hour.
ips_and_ports_for_this_time = dict()

# This is your log file you are reading from
# I am assuming this file is sorted by time.
# If it is not sorted this solution will not work.
with open(input_file) as log:
    # We need to keep track of the current hour (since you are grouping by hour)
    last_time = ''

    # For each line in the log
    for line in log:
        try:
          # The ip and port can be found via 'Servers:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxxx`
          ip_port = re.search(r'Servers:\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/\d{1,4}', line).group()
          # The xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx part of the ip_port string is the server ip.
          server_ip = re.search(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', ip_port).group()
          # The .../xxxx part of the ip_port string is the server port.
          server_port = re.search(r'/\d+', ip_port).group()[1:]
          # The time stamp has the format xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx 
          # where each x is a number
          timestamp = re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', line).group()
          # Convert it to iso 8601 and remove the minutes and seconds
          timestamp = datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").isoformat()[:-6]
        except AttributeError:
          # We couldnt find one of the fields in this log enter
          continue

        # If this is the first time we entered the loop then set our current time
        # to be equal to our last time.
        if not last_time:
            last_time = timestamp

        # If our last time and current time do not match
        # then we must be on a different hour so lets write
        # what is currently stored to a file
        if timestamp != last_time: 
            # For key (ip, port) and val (occurences) in our dict
            # write it to our output file.
            with open(output_file, 'a') as write_file:
                for key, val in ips_and_ports_for_this_time.items():
                    print("Writing {}".format('{} {} {} {}\n'.format(timestamp, key[0], key[1], val)))
                    # We will write each line to the file in the format:
                    # timestamp ip port occurences
                    write_file.write('{} {} {} {}\n'.format(timestamp, key[0], key[1], val))
            ips_and_ports_for_this_time = dict() # Reset our dict
            last_time = timestamp # Reset our last time to our current time.

        # If we have not seen this ip/port combination for this
        # time, then add it to our dict with 1 occurence.
        if (server_ip, server_port) not in ips_and_ports_for_this_time:
            ips_and_ports_for_this_time[(server_ip, server_port)] = 1
        else: # Else we have seen it before so increment the occurence.
            ips_and_ports_for_this_time[(server_ip, server_port)] += 1
        print(ips_and_ports_for_this_time)

# If we exited the loop and we have stuff in our dictionary
# we need to make sure to write it to our log_output file.
if ips_and_ports_for_this_time:
    with open(output_file, 'a') as write_file:
        for key, val in ips_and_ports_for_this_time.items():
            write_file.write('{} {} {} {}\n'.format(timestamp, key[0], key[1], val))
```